# Updating table schema with correct datatype in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I know that importing from CSV into SQLite treats all fields as text. According to [How to import csv file to sqlite with correct data types](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20240315/3701431), one can use

```
UPDATE MyTable SET MyColumn = CAST(MyColumn AS INTEGER)
```

to update whole colum type.  That seems to work, however that doesn't seem to be reflected in the output of `TYPEOF()` nor in `PRAGMA table_info(table_name)`

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE testtb (a TEXT, b TEXT);
sqlite> INSERT INTO testtb VALUES ('1', '2');
sqlite> UPDATE testtb SET b = CAST(b AS INTEGER);
sqlite> SELECT TYPEOF(b) FROM testtb;
text
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(testtb);
0|a|TEXT|0||0
1|b|TEXT|0||0
```

So how can I make the changes actually show up  when querying table's meta information (I'm lacking a proper phrasing here, but hopefully this makes sense) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want really want to, just use your first table as a staging table before you go ahead and create the final table with correct datatypes & data:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(testtb);
0|a|TEXT|0||0
1|b|TEXT|0||0
sqlite> create table testtb2 (a INT, b INT);
sqlite> insert into testtb2 (a,b) select a,b from testtb ;
sqlite> select * from testtb2;
1|2
sqlite> PRAGMA table_info(testtb2);
0|a|INT|0||0
1|b|INT|0||0
sqlite>
```

At the end of the day you have to remember (to some extent) that [sqlite doesn't actually care about datatypes](https://www.sqlite.org/quirks.html).

> SQLite is very flexible with regard to datatypes.
>
> Some commentators say that SQLite is "weakly typed" and that other SQL
> databases are "strongly typed". We consider these terms to be
> inaccurate and purgative. We prefer to say that SQLite is "flexibly
> typed" and that other SQL databases are "rigidly typed".
>
> The key point is that SQLite is very forgiving of the type of data
> that you put into the database. For example, if a column has a
> datatype of "INTEGER" and the application inserts a text string into
> that column, SQLite will first try to convert the text string into an
> integer, just like every other SQL database engine. Thus, if one
> inserts '1234' into an INTEGER column, that value is converted into an
> integer 1234 and stored. But, if you insert a non-numeric string like
> 'wxyz' into an INTEGER column, unlike other SQL databases, SQLite does
> not throw an error. Instead, SQLite stores the actual string value in
> the column.